# Permissions for users to view Report Library in SharePoint

Tags: permissions

Okay so i have created a report library with many dashboard pages stored in it. Problem is only users with contribute and owner permissions are able to view this and users with viewer and visitor permissions are not able to view this and it says error access is denied. how do i rectify this ?

i am using Moss 2007

Comment: Do the users with viewer permissions have access to the entire site, or only the one library?  The report library may contain additional resources like data connections and the security to each of those locations will also be required.

Comment: Yeah they have access to the entire site. Im using excel services for displaying charts and graphs in these pages but the viewers have been given read permissions also on that document library containing the excel file.